# two or more SVG Clip Path with same ID

Tags: javascript, svg

We have 2 svg clip paths defined in our HTML using javasript, where the ID for the clip paths are same. These are applied to 2 different controls.

But when we update any 1 clip path, it updates both the clip paths and the controls :(

Comment: IDs should be unique in the scope of the whole document. I once had to struggle with gradients spread over multiple svg images, which were combined within on html file.

Comment: Your file is invalid and as you have seen, bad things happen. Correct the file so that the ID values are unique.

Comment: such a terrible design choice on the part of the SVG authors...